# Can someone explain this code line by line?

Tags: c++

This method

```
bool isNumber(string input)
{
    char* p;

    strtod(input.c_str(), &p);
    return *p == 0;
}
```

should input a string and convert it to a double. But I do not understand the process of it. Can someone explain this to me in detail, line by line? And also, shouldn't bool be changed to double since it's not returning a true or false value? Thanks.

Comment: This function does not convert to double, it does check if the input string is convrtible to a double. `strtod` converts a string to double. [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/)

Comment: [It's pretty well explained in the reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof).

Comment: How's that question title helpful for future researchers? What don't you understand in particular? Ask more clear questions please! You may want to read [How to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strtod` tries to convert the string to a `double`. It also sets the `p` parameter to point to the position where the conversion ended.

If the conversion used all the characters in the string - if they were all part of a number - the pointer `p` will point to the `'\0'` terminator of the string.

So, `return *p == 0`, or better `return *p == '\0'`, tells us if we reached the end of the string. And, of course, `==` returns a `bool` result.

Comment: And since the first paramter of strtod() is a `const char*` and not a `std::string` that "raw" pointer of the string is retrieved via `input.c_str()`. The parameter (at the very least) should be marked as const as well.